# Google analytics sending wrong session control parameters

Tags: android, session, google-analytics

I have integrated Google Analytics in my android application. We are facing an issue, where Google Analytics automatically adds "sc=start" in the second hit. This results in 2 sessions in Google Analytics whereas user only performed one session.

I tried changing analytics code, and also tried opening different screens.

This is the code I am using to send ScreenView to GA :

```
 public static void sendAnalyticsScreenView(String screenName) {
    Tracker tracker = ErosApplication.getInstance().getTracker();
    if (tracker != null) {
        tracker.setScreenName(screenName);
        Map<String, String> build = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build();
        tracker.send(build);
    }
}
```

The getTracker Method is defined in Application class :

```
public synchronized Tracker getTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(ErosApplication.getInstance());
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
        mTracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    }
    return mTracker;

}
```

I also tried initializing  Google Analytics and Tracker in Application's onCreate :

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    ActivityLifecycleCallback.register(this);
    super.onCreate();

    sInstance = this;

    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).initialize();
    getTracker();
}
```

This is the logged data from terminal from GA :

```
12-07 11:37:02.861 D/GAv4    (18509): Hit delivery requested: ht=1481090822674, _s=0, _v=ma10.0.84, a=353190215, adid=5b2dae2c-79bd-4412-9c8b-bda72e961564, aid=com.tf.eros.faythTv, an=House of God, ate=1, av=1.4.2, cd=splash_screen, cid=2c02b7ba-9cac-4a10-b360-604a9390c2c1, sf=100.0, sr=1080x1920, t=screenview, tid=UA-80650025-7, ul=en-in, v=1
12-07 11:37:02.921 D/GAv4    (18509): Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
12-07 11:37:04.601 D/GAv4    (18509): Hit delivery requested: ht=1481090824407, _s=1, _v=ma10.0.84, a=353190216, adid=5b2dae2c-79bd-4412-9c8b-bda72e961564, aid=com.tf.eros.faythTv, an=House of God, ate=1, av=1.4.2, cd=new_intro, cid=2c02b7ba-9cac-4a10-b360-604a9390c2c1, sc=start, sf=100.0, sr=1080x1920, t=screenview, tid=UA-80650025-7, ul=en-in, v=1
```

I also tried calling the logScreenView method in splash screen 4 times at same place, like this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    AnalyticsHelper.logScreenView(getResources().getString(R.string.screen_splash));
    AnalyticsHelper.logScreenView(getResources().getString(R.string.screen_splash));
    AnalyticsHelper.logScreenView(getResources().getString(R.string.screen_splash));
    AnalyticsHelper.logScreenView(getResources().getString(R.string.screen_splash));
}
```

The terminal log :

```
12-07 11:42:26.635 D/GAv4    (24760): Hit delivery requested: ht=1481091146460, _s=0, _v=ma10.0.84, a=639766606, adid=5b2dae2c-79bd-4412-9c8b-bda72e961564, aid=com.tf.eros.faythTv, an=House of God, ate=1, av=1.4.2, cd=splash_screen, cid=6e9f3ca7-a87a-47bd-a80d-1619e6d9ac64, sf=100.0, sr=1080x1920, t=screenview, tid=UA-80650025-7, ul=en-in, v=1
12-07 11:42:26.645 D/GAv4    (24760): Hit delivery requested: ht=1481091146461, _s=1, _v=ma10.0.84, a=639766607, adid=5b2dae2c-79bd-4412-9c8b-bda72e961564, aid=com.tf.eros.faythTv, an=House of God, ate=1, av=1.4.2, cd=splash_screen, cid=6e9f3ca7-a87a-47bd-a80d-1619e6d9ac64, sc=start, sf=100.0, sr=1080x1920, t=screenview, tid=UA-80650025-7, ul=en-in, v=1
12-07 11:42:26.665 D/GAv4    (24760): Hit delivery requested: ht=1481091146461, _s=2, _v=ma10.0.84, a=639766608, adid=5b2dae2c-79bd-4412-9c8b-bda72e961564, aid=com.tf.eros.faythTv, an=House of God, ate=1, av=1.4.2, cd=splash_screen, cid=6e9f3ca7-a87a-47bd-a80d-1619e6d9ac64, sf=100.0, sr=1080x1920, t=screenview, tid=UA-80650025-7, ul=en-in, v=1
12-07 11:42:26.665 D/GAv4    (24760): Hit delivery requested: ht=1481091146461, _s=3, _v=ma10.0.84, a=639766609, adid=5b2dae2c-79bd-4412-9c8b-bda72e961564, aid=com.tf.eros.faythTv, an=House of God, ate=1, av=1.4.2, cd=splash_screen, cid=6e9f3ca7-a87a-47bd-a80d-1619e6d9ac64, sf=100.0, sr=1080x1920, t=screenview, tid=UA-80650025-7, ul=en-in, v=1
```

The "sc=start" parameter is being added by GA in 2nd call which results in incorrect session number. Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was sending screenView hit in activity's onCreate method, but it should be sent from onResume method. Moving analytics code for screen views from onCreate to onResume solved the problem.